# Ввод с консоли на java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Laba1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    int a = 3, b = 0;
      for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
       {
       for (int j = 1; j <= (a + i - 1); j++)
        {
        if (j <= (a - i))
          { 
          System.out.print('.');
          b++;
          }
        else
        {
        System.out.print('*');
        }
         }
         for (int j = 1; j <= b; j++)
        {
        System.out.print('.');
        }
        b = 0;
        System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

Как дополнить программу, чтобы пользователь в консоли ввел число 10 и отобразилось 10 елочек. Если пользователь напишет число 5 => будет нарисовано 5 елочек

Comment: что за елочки? можно символ этот*

Comment: Программа рисует треугольник( Как елочка). Надо как-то дополнить ее, чтобы можно было в консоли значение вводить

Comment: Ответ дополнил!

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // Сканнер для ввода текста с кл-ры

        int a = sc.nextInt(); // Вводим с клавиатуры
        int b = 0;


        for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= (a + i - 1); j++) {
                if (j <= (a - i)) {
                    System.out.print('.');
                    b++;
                } else {
                    System.out.print('*');
                }
            }

            for (int j = 1; j <= b; j++) {
                System.out.print('.');

            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Совет: придерживайтесь стандарту написания кода!

Comment: судя по вопросу надр было вывести не "ёлку" больше, а именно несколько в ряд

Comment: Да, сколько укажет пользователь

Comment: Почему-то не выводится ничего в консоль

Comment: для начало надо ввести число, затем нажать на enter

Comment: ну если нужно несколько елок, то кинь все это дело в цикл, по такой же схеме. Приношу извинения, я подумал надо добавлять уровни елок.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Думаю, лучше заменить точку на пробел

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class PrintTrees {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter nums of tree: ");
            int input = scn.nextInt();
            for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
                printTree(input);
            }
        }

        public static void printTree(int input){
            int a = 3, b = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= (a + i - 1); j++) {
                    if (j <= (a - i)) {
                        System.out.print('.');
                        b++;
                    } else {
                        System.out.print('*');
                    }
                }
                for (int j = 1; j <= b; j++) {
                    System.out.print('.');
                }

                b = 0;
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
Output: 
..*..
.***.
*****
..*..
.***.
*****
..*..
.***.
*****
..*..
.***.
*****
..*..
.***.
*****
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот это добавте в `main`:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int trees;

while (true) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Input the number: ");
        trees = input.nextInt();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         continue;
    }
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо просто в цикле проверять функцией `nextInt`, пока не будет введено число. Сделайте так:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int num;

while (true) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Введите кол-во: ");
        num = in.nextInt();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) { continue; }
    break;
}
```